# How to install python and run a python file in a gitlab job

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, gitlab-ci

```
image : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 

.deploy: &deploy
      before_script:
        - apt-get update -y
      script:
        - cd source/
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - python build_file.py > swagger.yml
```

I want to run the build_file.py file and write the output to swagger.yml. So to run the file I need to install python. How can I do that?

Comment: Seems you have a Debian-based system there, so do it like any package management there with `apt`. Alternatively, use an image that comes with Python already installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please provide the script for that. It'll be really helpful

Comment: Can you specify what this script should do in a single sentence? For example, "how to calculate with Arabic numbers". You then type this into the search bar of your browser and look at the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different Docker image for each job, so you can split your deployment stage into multiple jobs. In one use the `python:3` image for example to run `pip` and generate the `swagger.yml`, then define it as an artifact that will be used by the next jobs.

Example (untested!) snippet:

```
deploy-swagger:
  image: python:3
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd source/
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python build_file.py > swagger.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - source/swagger.yml

deploy-dotnet:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - deploy-swagger
  script:
    - ls -l source/swagger.yml
    - ...
```

You could (probably should) also make the swagger generation be part of previous stage and set an expiration for the artifact. See [this blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/12/10/basics-of-gitlab-ci-updated/) for example.